# Maintain dropdown selected value after submisson

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form with a dropdown list and I am using select2 plugin for searchable dropdown. If there is an error on form submission the form page redirect with a message and the selected drop down value lose it value and user have to reselect it. How can I maintain the drop down value?

Comment: don't redirect use ajax for validation

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<option <?php if(isset($_POST['name_of_this_dropdown'])){echo 'selected';};?>>some_value_here</option>
```

Comment: its nor working. and let me share that i've tried
$this->input->post-> its working but this one removes the search option

Comment: You should provide more details otherwise no can understand what u habe tried, what u wanted, probably a bit details code.